# Property placeholders with YamlPropertiesFactoryBean and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am migrating a small "legacy" application to Spring Boot and ran into an issue with property placeholders in combination with a `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean`. The application uses Spring XML configuration.

I added a Spring Boot "main" to the project like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have placed an `application.yaml`  into `/config`. It is being picked up by Spring boot and I can access properties defined in it via property replacement (`${some.prop}`) in bean declarations in the imported spring-config.xml. E.g.

```
<bean id="myRouteBuilder" class="org.camelSpringBoot.test.MyRouteBuilder">
    <property name="someProp" value="${prop.from.application.yaml}"/>
</bean>
```

**Except** when using a `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` to read an additional, external configuration file: A property for the file location in the constructor arg of a `org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource` does not get resolved:

```
<bean id="yamlProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="resources">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
                <constructor-arg value="${service.config.loc}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

yields

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${service.config.loc}

If I hard-code the location of the external configuration then properties used in the external YAML file are not resolved either.

application.yaml:

```
security:
  keystore:
    loc:      /security/my.keystore
```

external config:

```
services:
  a:
    ssl:
      secret: ${security.keystore.loc}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot open keystore/truststore ${security.keystore.loc}

Note that the error complains about the verbatim property.

The `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` instance is declared in spring-config.xml like the other beans that successfully use property placeholders (meaning properties get replaced by their values). Why would it fail for the `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean`

Is it possible to enable placeholder resolution for the external YAML document?

Comment: Just adding a bean that reads a file into properties will not work. Next to that loading and resolving properties isn’t a multi passed based Solutions. So trying to add a properties object and expecting to have those resolved isn’t going to work. Also the property in your YAML is different that the placeholder you used.

Comment: @M.Deinum, well, lots of things in Spring (Boot) just work. ;-)  Anyway, the properties read from the YAML file also end up in the `Environment` as a property source. So I was wondering if the property replacement could be triggered by some clever configuration. (I don't see where the property name mismatch is? Can you be more precise or edit the question directly? Anyway, those are not the real values. The actual configuration contains application specific names.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is working what you are trying to do. The Property resolving takes place after a BeanDefinition is done, and therefore only working with Spring Beans, but not arbitrary files like your yaml file.

Most build tools (gradle, maven) contain a functionality to resolve those placeholder during build time. Might that be a solution for you?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment about the order of property resolution vs bean creation. About using Maven: The reason why I would like to use property resolution is because I need to be able to source the value from Java system properties or OS environment variables and only provide defaults as a fallback in the actual YAML configuration file. So build-time property resolution won't do the trick.

Comment: You can only use property resolution for Bean definitions. So your approach with the file is not working. You need to move this dynamic property to a Spring bean definition in order to work, or come up with a complete different approach. What are your sources of this dynamic value?

Comment: With Spring Boot I can use property resolution in the `/config/application.yaml`. ([see "Placeholders in Properties"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties)). So property resolution is not limited to Bean definitions, is it?

Comment: Yes but this is only usable with system/env variables. This is a typical [chicken/egg problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg). How should spring know what is the actual source?